# Scroll bottom of viewport to bottom of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following jQuery:

```
$(".car-hub-header-help").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

At the moment this will scroll down the page and when the top of the viewport reaches the element it will stop, however I would like the viewport scroll until the bottom of the viewport is inline with the element that I am targeting.

So far I have tried changing top to bottom and that didn't work, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("div1").scrollIntoView(false);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to scroll till the element is present at the bottom of the page.

The scroll position from the top = `offset position of the element from the top - current window height + height of element`

The code will look like

```
$(".car-hub-header-help").click(function() {

    var elTopOffset = $(".footer").offset().top;
    var elHeight = $(".footer").height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: elTopOffset - windowHeight + elHeight
    }, 2000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
$(".car-hub-header-help").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top - $(".footer").height() + $(window).height()
     }, 2000);
   });
```